# Como enviar mais de um opção de checkbox por email?

Tags: php

Estou tentando enviar mais de um checkbox marcado por email, com PHPMail, só consigo enviar o ultimo item marcado, tentei fazer um if com foreach mais não adiantou, talvez ainda não esteja sabendo fazer, como eu consigo colocar essa função nesse checkbox em baixo:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['checkbox'])) {
foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $check) {
       echo $check . "<br>";
}}


$Nome = $_REQUEST['Nome'];
$Tel = $_REQUEST['Tel'];
$Email = $_REQUEST['Email'];
$Mensagem = $_REQUEST['Mensagem'];

$mail->WordWrap = 50; 
$mail->IsHTML(true);     
$mail->Subject  =  "Contato do site Webwork"; // Assundo
$mail->Body     =   " Nome:</strong> $Nome \n<br />". // Usuario
                    " Tel.:</strong> $Tel \n<br />".
                    " Email:</strong> $Email \n<br /><br />".    // Email
                    " Mensagem:</strong> $Mensagem \n<br />"; // Mensagem
```

Queria imprimir a resposta de mais de um check no corpo do email, como eu faço isso?

```
<form action="executa.php" method="post" name="form1">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Primeiro" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Segundo" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Terceiro" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Quarta" />
<button type="submit" value="Enviar">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: No seu form campo do checkbox deve ter o `name` seguido de colchetes: `name="produtos[]"`

Comment: Existe mais de um **$_POST['nome']** ?

Comment: Já tinha, editei para colocar o form.

Comment: Eu consigo dar um echo, e aparece para mim, mas no email eu não sei como enviar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use o `implode()` para transforma o array de checkbox enviados em um string seperando os itens por um delimitador, feito concate esse resultado a sua mensagem:

```
$selecionados = !empty($_POST['checkbox']) ? implode(', ', $_POST['checkbox']) : '';

$mail->Body = 'Mensagem..... '. $seleciondos;
```

Comment: Ficou perfeito, muito obrigado.